# ReactJS app using Three.JS. How to render the VRButton?

Tags: reactjs, three.js

I'm learning React and trying to incorporate Three.JS into a sample app. I've used Three.JS' VR button before in plain JS application but I can't figure out how to render the button in React.

```
import { VRButton } from 'three/examples/jsm/webxr/VRButton.js';
document.body.appendChild( VRButton.createButton( renderer ) );
```

I've tried storing the HTML output into a variable and rendering it in the component's `render` function like this but nothing is rendered.

```
return (
    /* other HTML*/
    { this.vrbutton }
)
```

How do I go about rendering this button?

https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/How-to-create-VR-content

Answer (score 1):

I think React doesn't have access to the DOM until after the component has mounted. Have you seen the [component lifecycle diagram](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/)? You might need to use `componentDidMount()`

```js
import { VRButton } from 'three/examples/jsm/webxr/VRButton.js';

constructor() {
    this.state = {
        buttonElement: undefined
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    const btn = VRButton.createButton( renderer );
    console.log(btn);  // Just to make sure it's being generated

    this.setState({
        buttonElement: btn
    });
}

render() {
    return(this.state.buttonElement);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I need the renderer object from the other component so I suppose passing it in here as a prop is the React way to do it. I'll try this out.